# making a character mesh collide with surfaces

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I'm wondering if there is a way to make it so that my character mesh collides with all other surfaces in the animation process so that i don't accidentally put feet through the floor or fingers through held objects.

I was also wondering if there is a way to do this between rigs as well, like if i was animating a sword fight and i try to move one sword through the other, the other sword is automatically pushed back by the one i am moving.